# Django unit testing: assertEqual() fails

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am following the book "Test-Driven Development in Python" and have the following functions:

tests.py:

```
def testHomePageCanSaveAPostRequest(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['itemText'] = 'A new list item'

    response = homePage(request)
    if response:
        response = response.content.decode('UTF-8')

    self.assertIn('A new list item', response)

    expectedHTML = render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'itemText':'A new list item'})
    if expectedHTML:
        expectedHTML = expectedHTML.content.decode('UTF-8')

    print(response)
    print(expectedHTML)
    if response==expectedHTML:
        print('Same')

    self.assertIn('A new list item', expectedHTML)

    self.assertEqual(response, expectedHTML)
```

views.py

```
def homePage(request):
    print(request.POST.get('itemText'))
    return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'itemText':request.POST.get('itemText')})
```

home.html:

```
...
<form method=POST>
  <input id=newItem name=itemText placeholder="Enter a to-do item">
</form>
<table id=listTable>
  <tr><td>{{itemText}}</td></tr>
</table>
...
```

Both `assertIn(..., response)` and `assertIn(..., expectedHTML)` are successful, which means both  `response` and `expectedHTML` have 'A new list item' in them.

I also print out `response` and `expectedHMTL`, and they look exactly the same. The comparison also print out 'Same' showing that they are the same.

However, the `assertEqual` fails with the following line by line comparison:

```
...
  <table id=listTable>
-   <tr><td>None</td></tr>
?           ----
+   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
...
```

One is None and the other is empty.? What did I do wrong?

EDIT:
The entire test output is listed in the following:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
A new list item
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>To do list</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your to do list</h1>
<form method=POST>
  <input id=newItem name=itemText placeholder="Enter a to-do item">
</form>
<table id=listTable>
  <tr><td>A new list item</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>To do list</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your to do list</h1>
<form method=POST>
  <input id=newItem name=itemText placeholder="Enter a to-do item">
</form>
<table id=listTable>
  <tr><td>A new list item</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
Same
.None
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: testHomePageReturnsCorrectHTML (lists.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yltang/course/TDD/lecture/python/webapps/git/superlists/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 27, in testHomePageReturnsCorrectHTML
    self.assertEqual(response, expectedHTML)
AssertionError: '<!do[231 chars]stTable>\n  <tr><td>None</td></tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>' != '<!do[231 chars]stTable>\n  <tr><td></td></tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>'
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>To do list</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Your to do list</h1>
  <form method=POST>
    <input id=newItem name=itemText placeholder="Enter a to-do item">
  </form>
  <table id=listTable>
-   <tr><td>None</td></tr>
?           ----
+   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.017s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: The message is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the print statements to a different test. The print statements are in `testHomePageCanSaveAPostRequest`, which is passing.

The failing test is `testHomePageReturnsCorrectHTML`, which you have not included in your question.

Comment: Yes, right. I got it. I think the book is a little bit misleading. Thanks a million Alasdair.